# What diffrence does a space between dbname and = does in PDO

Tags: php

This is the code when I try connecting to database. I have intentionally given wrong database name.

```
<?php
   try 
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ehrp', 'root', '');

    }   

        catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();

    }

?>
```

This is the exception that I get, which is fine :
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'ehrp'

But when I write this :
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname =ehrp', 'root', '');

Notice a space between dbname and = I get nothing on screen.No error is shown.
Why is that?

Comment: is this literally all your code, or are you including this in something bigger? (i.e. is the code you show a true [mcve]?)

Comment: No just this much.

Comment: `SHOW DATABASES;` execute this query and tell me if you found your database `ehrp`

Comment: Where are you viewing your errors? In the browser? If so, you would not expect to see an error with the second case (with the space in it), because it is going to be fatal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument you're passing to the PDO constructor is in URI form, and a URI cannot contain arbitrary spaces, they all mean something. So what you've actually supplied the PDO constructor as far as it can tell is `mysql:host=localhost;` followed by an assigned property called "database " (with a space at the end). Since PDO does not know anything about a property called "database " there are no errors (it's a legal URI property value assignment), and as an unknown property, it just gets ignored. No errors, no warnings, you've done nothing wrong and PDO does what you ask it do to.

The PDO connection to your server on localhost succeeds, and you now have a PDO instance that is connected, and simply has not been tied to a specific database yet.

To verify this, prepare a `SELECT DATABASE()` statement with your PDO object, and then execute it: it should work just fine, and come back with a response indicating that you're not connected to a database yet.